# HTML area shapes and mobile phones: is this a bug and is there a workaround?

Tags: html, mobile, area, shapes

My website has a very precise "area shape" definition. It's pixel perfect.

Here's [my website](http://papdevis.fr/)

Move your mouse over the departments on the left, you'll see the departements highlight on the right. If you move the mouse over the departments, you'll see that it's a pixel-perfect precision.

My big problem is about "Ile de France", which is the center of the France, almost 1/5 of the population lives here, so what follows is a huge problem to me.

Nota: **before** *trying on your mobile phone* (if you do so), just verify that what I'm saying is true: on your PC, go to the main page (link before), zoom in (`ctrl +` keyboard shortcut) and move your mouse over the department "Ile de France". You'll see that the precision is perfect: move out of the department, move in, you'll see by yourself the precision of the "detection".

On my Sony Ericsson Xperia Arc, the way "area shape" is handled is a huge problem.

Here's what it gives when I try to click on "Ile de France":

[image: Here's what it gives when I try to click on "Ile de France" (view far from mobile)]

Getting closer (to show the problem):

[image: Here's what it gives when I try to click on "Ile de France" (getting closer)]

Getting even closer:

[image: Here's what it gives when I try to click on "Ile de France" (even closer)]

And to show which departement is selected:

[image: Here's what it gives when I try to click on "Ile de France" (show the bad department clicked)]

As you can see from the lastest picture, the map is very enlarged, but it still doesn't want to select "Ile de France", whereas I clearly click on the very middle of the region.

I mean I've been working for 3 days to get a map of France *that* precise, I wouldn't like to throw away that work and do a coarse work...

Is this a bug? Is this considered a normal behavior? Do "iPhone" mobiles have the same problem? Do you have a workaround?

-Edit-

According to Andrei G, it seems to work on GalaxyS2, but still need to enlarge the map...

-Edit-

I've got exactly the same problem on some Android tablets. I need to make a "mobile" version. This is soo stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no problem with your map. The issue is that a human finger is not nearly as accurate as the mouse. If you enlarge your map enough, you'll be able to select the appropriate region.

I used GalaxyS2 to go to your site.

Also, the hover effect is not going to work with a phone, as the people don't drag their fingers on the screen when they want to click your area.

Comment: If you press your finger and let it pressed on the map, it simulates "hover". At least that's what it does on my Xperia Arc.

Comment: `a human finger is not nearly as accurate as the mouse` => I knew that, I've tested with a *very enlarged* map: my latest pics prove it, and I thought that the latest one would already show that, even though it's *very enlarged* it doesn't click on "ile de France". I can't explain it better than the pictures... sorry...

Comment: I saw your picture, I just wanted to let you know that I had no trouble clicking the area when I enlarged the map on my phone

Comment: So do you suggest this could come from my `Sony Ericsson Xperia Arc`? This would explain why Sony has left the `Ericsson` division... just kidding...

Comment: you could try creating a separate version of your website for mobile, where the map would take up most of the screen. That way the users don't have to zoom  in that much.

Comment: Ok, you're right... I was just asking if there was a "known workaround" for such problem (JavaScript library or whatever) because doing such a precise map is a lot of work.

Comment: I'm thinking about making a "mobile map". What "acceptable" maximum size would you advice?

Comment: I'd say you only display a small header (1 text line) and let the map fill the rest of the screen.

Comment: This would imply that French people know where their department is, which is almost never the case (sorry for the French people that do know `;^D`)

Comment: Ok so one line: "choose your departement" with an option on the right "search by name"

Comment: yes, that would allow for the maximum amount of space to display the map

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a map in a HTML email when viewed on my Android phone. I was using the map tag with both the name and id attributes. When I removed the name attribute and just used the id attribute instead I was able to accurately tap the hotspot on my phone.